# two icons appearing for the same application

Tags: snap, okular

I installed okular using snap package. After installation, I see [okular with two icons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRYod.png) in show application, and both applications open an okular window after double-clicked.

Why do I get two different icons for the same application, and is there a difference between them? Is it possible to remove one of them?

Comment: Once I run `sudo snap remove okular`, both applications disappear. Does snap automatically installed apt package as well?

Comment: Canonical's obsession with snap packages has messed things up. I have seen a case where the `apt` command actually installed the snap version (maybe because it was the only available version; I don't remember). Which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: @FedKad I am using 20.04. I run `apt list --installed grep okular` and nothing shows up. I believe this means that I do not have apt okular installed? (I am new to linux so I am not sure if this command is correct though)

Comment: No. snap should not install the apt package automatically (but the chromium apt package installs the snap package). Since nothing shows up in `apt list --installed grep okular`, it must be that you don't have the apt version of Okular.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi I opened ubuntu software and see that okular is installed. Does that mean I actually have an apt version? I am so confused right now.

Comment: In recent version of Ubuntu, software center uses the snap version. In case you are still confused, use the terminal to check. `snap list | grep okular`.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi thank you for the information! (and the quick response :D)

Answer (score 2):

Unless you need the latest version of Okular for some reason, you can just use the apt version of Okular to fix this issue.

Open a terminal and enter the following commands.

```
sudo snap remove okular
sudo apt install okular
```

---

If you really need the latest version of Okular, I would suggest flatpak instead. First, ensure that the apt and the snap versions are not installed.

```
sudo apt remove okular && sudo snap remove okular
```

Instal flatpak, if already not installed.

```
sudo apt install flatpak
flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo
```

Now install okular with flatpak

```
flatpak install flathub org.kde.okular
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions! You remind me that snap automatically update packages. I think I would just install okular with apt since I prefer to keep my package managing simple.

Comment: @popularcoffee You can [accept my answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow), if it answers your question.

Comment: I want to keep it open for a while. I am still curious about the reason why two icons appearing for the same application.

Comment: @popularcoffee Sure. I guess, it is some issue with the snap packaging (which only the maintainers of the snap package can fix), but let's see if there are other answers.